# Should I worry about these green lentils?

Tags: lentils

[image: Green lentils]
I bought this pack of organic green lentils.
Just noticed that the bag has some particles which accumulated at the bottom of the pack. Any idea what these are? Is this something I should worry about?
Thank you!

Comment: I can't tell from the photo: are they wet or dry in the pack?

Comment: They are dry, well packed

Answer (score 7):

That just looks like some chaff from the harvesting and packaging process.  It's good practice to always rinse beans before use.  Lentils (organic or not) are no exception.  Place in a bowl, fill with water and drain a couple of times.  You should be good to go.